# Animation frame images for UIImageView animation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, animation

Is there any software to get the images for animation frames for UIImageView. How to create those images? Is there any website which can help me with the images .I really want to add animation for my application but i am not able to get the images for it. How to design or get the images for animation?

Comment: Even though I did answer this question, I don't think it is relevant for Stack Overflow, as it's not a programming question. The questioner knows how to use the `UIImageView` class and its `animationImages` API, but wants to know about asset creation/artwork.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any image editor. Notable apps are:

- Photoshop (paid)
- Pixelmator (paid)
- the GIMP (free)

You would create the animation frames in the same way you create any other image - except there would be multiple images, advancing the frames of the animation - rather than a single image.